# convert string that contains characters into integers in java

Tags: java, string, netbeans, search-engine, binary-search

I want to know if we can convert a string like "pink" to integer using java.

here is my example:

```
   string word = "pink";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(word);
```

I was thinking in a code that convert words to integers. because I want to convert all words in my project to integers and then apply binary search to search for a word in these document. I do not no if it is an applicable idea but I think that it will be fast if it is applicable.

Comment: Maybe using `enum` is useful. like this `enum Color {
    
    PINK("pink",1),
    RED("red",2);
    
    private String name;
    private int value;

    Color(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}`

Comment: what is the expected result from `pink` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I've a strong feeling it could be done without the need to convert strings to integers

Comment: What you are describing is called "computing a hash code", and  all Java classes (including  `String`) have the method `int hashCode()` that does exactly that.  Java also includes collections such as `HashMap` and `HashSet` which take advantage of these hash codes to provide speedy access to their contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can make word to integer map like this.

```
List<String> allWords = Arrays.asList("cat", "Dog", "Fish", "Cat", "dog");
Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : allWords)
    wordMap.computeIfAbsent(word.toLowerCase(), k -> wordMap.size());
System.out.println(wordMap);
```

->

```
{fish=2, cat=0, dog=1}
```